# Exporting geemap object as tiff and shapefile

Tags: python, geospatial, arcgis, google-earth-engine, geemap

I am new to geospatial analysis and geemap package. I am trying to add a couple of soil-climate data to geemap and with a boundary of Canada. Then I want to export the geemap object as a raster tiff image as well as shapefile. I have tried writing some, and the code works (although to my little understanding as a newbie). However, I don't seem to get the data export aspect correctly. I would appreciate any help to make this work. Thanks.

```
Map = geemap.Map()

PR = ee.FeatureCollection('projects/taiwo-2023/assets/CA_2016_digital_boundary_file')
Map.centerObject(PR)


# Add pH data to map4/1AfJohXnONRbC6gJpKvJhTmwL_bhWQWh-LP0BBz1c-pciH2FFyQZGP7XV4m4
pH = ee.Image("OpenLandMap/SOL/SOL_PH-H2O_USDA-4C1A2A_M/v02")
pH_visualization = {
  'bands': ['b30'],
  'min': 42.0,
  'max': 110.0,
  'palette': [
    "FF0000","FF1C00","FF3900","FF5500","FF7100","FF8E00",
    "FFAA00","FFC600","FFE200","FFFF00","E3FF00","C7FF00",
    "AAFF00","8EFF00","72FF00","55FF00","39FF00","1DFF00",
    "01FF00","00FF1C","00FF38","00FF54","00FF71","00FF8D",
    "00FFA9","00FFC6","00FFE2","00FFFE","00E3FF","00C7FF",
    "00ABFF","008FFF","0072FF","0056FF","003AFF","001DFF",
    "0001FF","1B00FF","3800FF","5400FF",
  ]
}
Map.addLayer(pH.clip(PR), pH_visualization, "Soil pH x 10 in H2O", opacity=0.5)




# Add texture data to map
texture = ee.Image("OpenLandMap/SOL/SOL_TEXTURE-CLASS_USDA-TT_M/v02")
visualization = {
  'bands': ['b0'],
  'min': 1.0,
  'max': 12.0,
  'palette': [
    "d5c36b","b96947","9d3706","ae868f","f86714","46d143",
    "368f20","3e5a14","ffd557","fff72e","ff5a9d","ff005b",
  ]
}
Map.addLayer(texture.clip(PR), visualization, "Soil texture class (USDA system)")


# Organic carbon
oc = ee.Image("OpenLandMap/SOL/SOL_ORGANIC-CARBON_USDA-6A1C_M/v02")
visualization = {
  'bands': ['b0'],
  'min': 0.0,
  'max': 120.0,
  'palette': [
    "ffffa0","f7fcb9","d9f0a3","addd8e","78c679","41ab5d",
    "238443","005b29","004b29","012b13","00120b",
  ]
}
Map.addLayer(oc.clip(PR), visualization, "Soil organic carbon content in x 5 g / kg")


# Bulk density
bulk = ee.Image("OpenLandMap/SOL/SOL_BULKDENS-FINEEARTH_USDA-4A1H_M/v02")
visualization = {
  'bands': ['b0'],
  'min': 5.0,
  'max': 185.0,
  'palette': ['5e3c99', 'b2abd2', 'f7e0b2', 'fdb863', 'e63b01']
}
Map.addLayer(bulk.clip(PR), visualization, "Soil bulk density in x 10 kg / m3")


# Add Agriculture and Agri-Food Canada annual crop inventory
#AAFC = ee.ImageCollection('AAFC/ACI')
#AAFC = AAFC.filter(ee.Filter.date('2014-01-01', '2014-12-31')).first()
#Map.addLayer(AAFC, {}, 'AAFC')


# Precipitation
precipitation = ee.ImageCollection('NASA/GPM_L3/IMERG_MONTHLY_V06').filterDate('2010-01-01', '2010-12-31')
precipitation = precipitation.select('precipitation').reduce(ee.Reducer.sum())
Map.addLayer(precipitation.clip(PR), {}, 'GPM_Precipitation')


# Surface temperature
surface_temp = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2").filterDate('2013-06-01', '2013-08-31')
surface_temp = surface_temp.select('ST_B10').reduce(ee.Reducer.sum())
Map.addLayer(surface_temp.clip(PR), {}, "surface_temp");


# Elevation: slope and aspect
elevation = ee.ImageCollection('JAXA/ALOS/AW3D30/V3_2').select('DSM')
proj_slope = elevation.first().select(0).projection()
slope = ee.Terrain.slope(elevation.mosaic().setDefaultProjection(proj_slope))

Map.addLayer(slope.clip(PR), {}, "slope");

aspect = ee.Terrain.aspect(elevation.mosaic().setDefaultProjection(proj_slope))
Map.addLayer(aspect.clip(PR), {}, "aspect");


# Soil Water Content
soil_water_content = ee.Image("OpenLandMap/SOL/SOL_WATERCONTENT-33KPA_USDA-4B1C_M/v01")
visualization = {
  'bands': ['b0'],
  'min': 0.0,
  'max': 52.9740182135385,
  'palette': [
    "d29642","eec764","b4ee87","32eeeb","0c78ee","2601b7",
    "083371",
  ]
}
Map.addLayer(soil_water_content.clip(PR), visualization, "Soil water content at 33kPa (field capacity)")


# Air Temp
air_temp = ee.ImageCollection('NASA/GLDAS/V021/NOAH/G025/T3H').filterDate('2013-06-01', '2013-08-31')
air_temp = air_temp.select('Tair_f_inst').reduce(ee.Reducer.sum())
Map.addLayer(air_temp.clip(PR), {}, 'air temp')


# Humidity
humidity = ee.ImageCollection('NASA/GLDAS/V021/NOAH/G025/T3H').filterDate('2013-06-01', '2013-08-31')
humidity = humidity.select('Qair_f_inst').reduce(ee.Reducer.sum())
Map.addLayer(humidity.clip(PR), {}, 'humidity')


# Soil Moisture
soil_moisture = ee.ImageCollection('NASA/GLDAS/V021/NOAH/G025/T3H').filterDate('2013-06-01', '2013-08-31')
soil_moisture = soil_moisture.select('SoilMoi10_40cm_inst').reduce(ee.Reducer.sum())
Map.addLayer(soil_moisture.clip(PR), {}, 'soil_moisture')

Map
```